# How can the J&J vaccine shot be effective against COVID-19 if it only has a ~60% efficacy rate?

Tags: covid-19, vaccine

According to the [CDC's page on the safety of J&J vaccines](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/different-vaccines/janssen.html), the reported efficacy rate of the vaccine is a staggeringly low 66.3%.

That said, the government is still promoting and touting the J&J vaccine as a reliable and effective way to protect oneself against the effects of the COVID-19 virus.

In a report published just yesterday, the [CDC published an official study on 32,867 COVID vaccinated people](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/70/wr/mm7037e2.htm?s_cid=mm7037e2_w) and found numbers that closely matched those of the clinical trials mentioned above, in that Moderna is 95% effective at preventing hospitalization, followed by Pfizer at 80% and J&J at 60%.

So if the numbers are correct, why is J&J still touted as an effective protection against COVID-19 still? 60% isn't exactly the greatest confidence booster -- that's almost at the level of a coin flip. How can the J&J vaccine shot be effective against COVID-19 if it only has a ~60% efficacy rate?  Pfizer/BioNTech and Moderna's vaccines offer a much more solid guarantee, but 60% for J&J?

How can 60% be considered effective?

Comment: An efficacy rate of 60% means the vaccine was effective in 60% of people they tested. So it is effective, just not as effective **percentage-wise** as some others. If those others are not available, J&J would be better than nothing

Comment: Also asked on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52328/how-can-the-jj-vaccine-shot-be-effective-against-covid-19-if-it-only-has-a-60 Alas I answered there before I saw this one...

Comment: This is another reason why cross-posting is frowned upon on SE. The question on Skeptics has been closed as opinion-based, so Fizz's (good) answer is wasted. I don't think this is opinion-based, and since Skeptics has closed the duplicate question, @Fizz is free to copy the answer here.

Comment: It's important to remember that reported efficacy depends on the specific dosing regimen and on trial duration.  J&J focused on single-dosing for non-efficacy reasons, chiefly to provide a solution for populations that would be unlikely to have easy access to a 2nd dose.  Efficacy (for obvious reasons) has been measured relatively soon after vaccination. There are now some indications that the Pfizer mRNA vaccine may have a faster decrease in efficacy than the AstraZeneca adenovirus vaccine; the J&J adenovirus vaccine may end up providing longer protection, especially with a 2nd booster dose.

Comment: Re: "that's almost at the level of a coin flip." This is incorrect - the efficacy means that 60% of the people who otherwise would have been hospitalized will not be hospitalized. That is, people who would have had a 100% chance of being hospitalized, with the vaccine only have a 40% chance of being hospitalized.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that we are asking vaccines to prevent disease, and further hospitalization, not infection. Others have already noted the misinterpretation, so I will wait and see if @Fizz ‘s answer is forthcoming and this question stays open. If it is left hanging for awhile I will try to come back to take a shot at it.